# Tokenize elements from a text file by removing comments, extra spaces and blank lines in C++

Tags: c++, file, comments, token, space

I'm trying to eliminate comments, blank lines and extra spaces within a text file, then tokenize the elements leftover. Each token needs a space before and after.

```
exampleFile.txt
var

/* declare variables */a1 ,
b2a ,     c,
```

Here's what's working as of now,

```
string line; //line: represents one line of text from file
ifstream InputFile("exampleFile", ios::in); //read from exampleFile.txt

//Remove comments
while (InputFile && getline(InputFile, line, '\0'))
{
    while (line.find("/*") != string::npos)
    {
        size_t Begin = line.find("/*");
        line.erase(Begin, (line.find("*/", Begin) - Begin) + 2);
        // Start at Begin, erase from Begin to where */ is found
    }   
}
```

This removes comments, but I can't seem to figure out a way to tokenize while this is happening.

So my questions are:

- Is it possible to remove comments, spaces, and empty lines and tokenize all in this while statement?
- How can I implement a function to add spaces in between each token before they are tokenized? Tokens like c, need to be recognized as c and , individually.

Thank you in advanced for the help!

Comment: Off topic: Save yourself a search: `while ((size_t Begin =line.find("/*")) != string::npos)`

Comment: Off topic: What if the block comment does not end on the same line?

Comment: And another off topic: Think about what will happen when the program finds the /* in `while (line.find("/*") != string::npos)`.

Comment: @user4581301 thank you for responding! Good tip to add that in the while loop. From my understanding, if the comment does not end on the same line this method is still okay. I'm able to remove any comments between \* and *\ . the text in between is removed, correct?

Comment: Unfortunately no. What will happen if the comment doesn't end is you will erase the end of the line and then go back to looking for `"/*"` on the next line, not the closing `"*/"`. You're going to need a [state machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine) of sorts to track what sorts of inputs you are looking for and handle them correctly. For example, in *Normal* state, a `"/*"` is found. This changes the machine's state to *Block Comment*. *Block Comment* looks for a `"*/"` and discards everything else. When `"*/"` is found the machine changes state back to *Normal*.

Comment: There are tools to do this. Look up lex/yacc.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to skip whitespace characters and you don't care about new lines then I'd recommend reading the file with `operator>>`.
You could write simply:

```
std::string word;
bool isComment = false;
while(file >> word)
{
    if (isInsideComment(word, isComment))
        continue;

     // do processing of the tokens here
     std::cout << word << std::endl;
}
```

Where the helper function could be implemented as follows:

```
bool isInsideComment(std::string &word, bool &isComment)
{
    const std::string tagStart = "/*";
    const std::string tagStop = "*/";

    // match start marker
    if (std::equal(tagStart.rbegin(), tagStart.rend(), word.rbegin())) // ends with tagStart
    {
        isComment = true;
        if (word == tagStart)
            return true;

        word = word.substr(0, word.find(tagStart));
        return false;
    }

    // match end marker
    if (isComment)
    {
        if (std::equal(tagStop.begin(), tagStop.end(), word.begin())) // starts with tagStop
        {
            isComment = false;
            word = word.substr(tagStop.size());
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

For your example this would print out:

```
var
a1
,
b2a
,
c,
```

The above logic should also handle multiline comments if you're interested.

However, denote that the function implementation should be modified according to what are your assumptions regarding the comment tokens. For instance, are they always separated with whitespaces from other `words`? Or is it possible that a `var1/*comment*/var2` expression would be parsed? The above example won't work in such situation.

Hence, another option would be (what you already started implementing) reading lines or even chunks of data from the file (to assure begin and end comment tokens are matched) and learning positions of the comment markers with find or [regex](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/) to remove them afterwards.

Comment: I understand, this is helpful! Thank you!

Comment: `line == tagStart` only catches for the entire string. When reading a line from the file, line is set to the whole line. So I need to compare part of the string to "/*" or "*/", using like line[i] + line[i+1], but that brings me to type errors.

Comment: Not sure if I understand you correct. To avoid confusion I've updated the variable name `line` to `word` since this is what it contains (not the file line in general). If you need to handle cases like `var/* comment */var` I've also updated the function to use `std::equal`. But as I wrote, this is a general idea and should be adapted to your specific needs. There are probably more details you haven't shared in the question which would require implementation updates.